# How to Make Pose Position same as Rest Position

Tags: armature

I'm having trouble resetting the pose position (Top Picture). I want the bones to have the same position/rotation as my rest position (Bottom Picture). I've looked at all the tips and I've tried selecting all my bones in pose position by doing Alt-G, Alt-R, and Alt-S but to no avail, they didn't change at all.

Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the only thing causing you issues is the IK constraints on the limbs. Go to each constraint and adjust the pole angle until it looks like the rest position. If you enable the display axes options you will have an easier time seeing which way you should adjust the angle as well.

Comment: Thank you! I just had to alter the pole positions and try to match my original armature.